# Creating a graph on the surface of an object

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to achieve a robot in blender, but I am stuck at a part where I have to make a sort of graph. Here's what I mean

[image]

I've been trying to add cubes, shrink them, resize, and rotate them, but I never get a good outcome. I was wondering how I could make it close enough to the actual picture. I am not rendering it, I am going to 3d print it. Heres what I have so far.[image]

Comment: You want to model them? Texture? Paint?

Comment: Single image. I just want to model  the graph.

Comment: @cegaton I edited my question.

Comment: @cegaton Edited, added picture, added more in desc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way that I know of, maybe someone else will have something better...

1.) Add your picture via ***Background Images***:

[image]

---

---

2.) Add plane and delete 3 of the vertices.

3.) Extrude vertices using <kbd>E</kbd> or by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftClick</kbd>

4.) After final vertex has been added, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd> the first vertex and press <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face from the vertices:

[image]

---

---

Drag vertices using <kbd>G</kbd> to fine tune their placement:

[image]

---

---

Finally, in *Object Mode*, select the ***Graph*** *first* then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd> the Robot (the cube in the following gif) then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go into *Edit Mode* (you will be editing the Robot).  *Make sure your View is in **Orthographic** and you are facing the graph at a 90 degree angle* (as shown) and, only then, select "***Knife Project***":

[image]

This will cut the graph into the robot.  Press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude the faces out from the robot.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I used photoshop to draw it, then converted to svg and imported, but this is so much cleaner and easier!

Comment: @Visastar - You're very welcome

Answer (score 3):

You may do it using a ***curve*** and then convert it to *mesh*.
[image]

Add a curve, scale it to make it longer and then subdivide many times with <kbd>W</kbd> (set the segments number in a *Tool Shelf*). Form its shape as you like (to be accurate use *background image* as a reference).
[image]

Select all points with <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>V</kbd>-->*Vector* to change the handle type. Add *bezier circle* and do the same with it. Rotate it 45 degrees (you may change the circle's shape as you like though).
[image]

Select the curve and go to the *Curve* header, set it's type to *2D*. Set the *bezier circle* as a *Bevel Object* target. Check the *Fill Caps* checkbox in a *Geometry* panel. Scale the *bezier circle* to adjust the curve's thickness. Finally press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>-->*Convert to Mesh* in *Object Mode*.
[image]

Enable *Auto Smooth* checkbox in the *Normals* panel of the *Mesh Data* header to make the object smooth.
[image]

Use a *snapping tool* to attach the curved mesh to your robot. Click the *magnet icon* and change the snap element type to *Face*.
[image]